# Unity JsonUtility doesn't properly convert string to an object

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am using JsonUtility to deserialize from json string to a Packet.

```
if (client.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
    {
        var ns = client.GetStream();

        Byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        ns.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); //the message incoming
        var packet = JsonUtility.FromJson<Packet>(msg);
        return packet;
    }
```

The `msg` when I receive it is: `{"Command":0, "Message":"Hello Client..."}`

I am trying to convert it into a Packet class that looks like this:

```
public class Packet
{
    public Command Command { get; set; }
    public object Message { get; set; }
}
```

However, after I convert it the Packet is as follow:

```
{
    "Command": "Message",
    "Message": null
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or if there are any alternatives? (Other than NewtonSoft as it has issues in Unity)

Comment: Why do you need object and not string though?

Comment: Because I am sending through integers, classes and booleans, states, and more.

Comment: Do yo know before you deserialise if it's going to be an int, class, etc.?

Comment: @DavidG No I don't, I did think of using generics but can't think of a way to make it work. The question is really why JsonUtility can't deserialize it where other packages like Newtonsoft can. I accepted the other answer, because it does provide a workaround. But if you have another one I will be happy to accept yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is using types wrong,

you can do basically this:

```
public Packet returnAsJson(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<Packet>(jsonString);
    }
```

```
public class Packet
{
    public string Command;
    public string Message;
}
```

in your case this would return the `Packet` as an object with the json variables

---

*If you want to use object instead of string first make sure that you can create an object from the string, if this doesn't work you can create a new class

and create functions to get the strings into the class as the correct types

```
public class FinalPacket
{
    public command Command;
    public object Message;
}

public void FinalPacket(Packet pak)
{
//put the variables to the new class
}
```

Comment: There may be a good reason why OP needs to use `object`, that's why I asked in a comment.

Comment: fixed that with another solution

Comment: None of these will work ;) a) `Command` is an `int` not an`string` (it's not wrapped in `"`) b) the class needs to be tagged `[Serializable]` otherwise Unity can't deserialize it at all. c) `object` is not serializable either so the second thing can't work! It is a `string` (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67524112/7111561))